# mmap a same file in both C and Python, will it really use the shared memory? will mmap work across different programming languages?

Tags: python, c, mmap, cross-language

By doing the reading from C code and writing from python, I couldn't see in my C the changes that i am doing in python.

Hence I would really like to know whether mmap work across language like C and Python or am I doing mistakes here, Please let me know.

Reading from C Code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *shared;
    int fd = -1;
    if ((fd = open("hello.txt", O_RDWR, 0)) == -1) {
        printf("unable to open");
        return 0;
    }
    shared = (char *)mmap(NULL, 1, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    printf("%c\n",shared[0]);
}
```

## Writing from Python

```
with open( "hello.txt", "wb" ) as fd:
    fd.write("1")
with open( "hello.txt", "r+b" ) as fd:
    mm = mmap.mmap(fd.fileno(), 1, access=ACCESS_WRITE, offset=0)
    print("content read from file")
    print(mm.readline())
    mm[0] = "0"
    print("content read from file")
    print(mm.readline())
    mm.close()
    fd.close()
```

Comment: Your C code creates an anonymous mapping. Your Python code maps a file called "hello.txt". They had better not be the same mapping. Or did you intend to map "hello.txt" in your C program?

Comment: Ya, I intend to map hello.txt in my c program. I tried only with MAP_SHARED but couldn't make it to work. I thought, doing mmap with the same files, will start providing the data from the mapped memory region of the file and not exactly from the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your C program, your `mmap()` creates an anonymous mapping, not a file-based mapping. You probably want to specify `fd` instead of `-1` and omit the `MAP_ANON` symbol.

```
shared = (char *)mmap(NULL, 1, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rob.